# How to add a custom north arrow to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I created a custom north arrow in Inkscape, now I cannot seem to add it to ArGIS 10.1.  I would ideally like for it to be displayed in the north arrow selector window (See attached image).  How can I add my custom north arrow to ArcMap 10.1?

[image]

Comment: How To turn on the north arrow and scale bar button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your own custom North Arrow via the Style Manager

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000008000000

**Your image needs to be in EMF format**

http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=27

Comment: Actually, in ArcGIS 10.1, it supports bmp, emf, png, jpg, and gif symbols.  The con is that the symbol doesn't scale well, unless it's emf or another vectorized format.

Comment: Actually, ArcMap 10.1 does not support PNG with transparency

Comment: The that is technically an ESRI ArcGIS 'bug' previous versions have supported transparency.